# How to block this specific user-agent on .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, cpanel

I would like to block this user-agent via .htaccess - " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko ". Can somebody help me identify what kind of system/browser is this? I am using a cpanel hosting and this is the user agent that the visitors tab shows. What command should I enter into .htaccess in order not to block too much or too little - just this specific user agent?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the .htaccess file to block that this particular user agent:

The htaccess content should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

**Remember**

You need to enable apache module `mod_rewrite`

Comment: Thanks, should i use the quotation marks (") ? RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko " [NC] or RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko [NC]

Comment: Would these visit attempts still be logged in cpanel visitors log or I shouldn't see any logs coming from this user-agent?

Comment: they will be logged