# How to block a user agent on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to block this user agent because it requests a lot of image data.

```
Tachiyomi Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0 1985775847
```

I have a Wordpress website and I can edit .htaccess file

Comment: I doubt it will work anyway (user can change agent name) but there's [wordpress - Blocking IP range in htaccess file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643803/blocking-ip-range-in-htaccess-file)

Comment: There's also [apache - How to block this specific user-agent on .htaccess - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671192/how-to-block-this-specific-user-agent-on-htaccess) and  [Setting up User-Agent blocking in .htaccess or my site is being attacked - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64588029/setting-up-user-agent-blocking-in-htaccess-or-my-site-is-being-attacked) although I don't have the exper size to term whether it's duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily block with .htaccess

In your case: ( **Please put this in the very beginning of the .htaccess file** )

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Tachiyomi [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

In above `Tachiyomi` is user agent name, if you have different name just replace it.

Comment: can I somehow add a note when the 403 forbidden occurs? like, you can't visit our website with Tachiyomi. Thanks for the answer though it helped me. Before I had added the full string that I send and it didn't help me.